# How to add colors to printed text?

Tags: python, colors

I am very new to Python/coding in general, and I'm working on a text-based game where two players work together to fight a Boss. It's close to finished, but I'd like to color some of the text.

I looked up my problem, and based on what I found I tried copying and pasting

- " `print("\033[1;32;40m Bright Green  \n")` "

  and
- " `print '\033[1;31mRed like Radish\033[1;m'` "

but neither worked.

I'm coding this in Atom and running it in IDLE.

There were no syntax errors, it simply printed the `\033[1;32;40m` along with the text, rather than coloring the text.

Comment: maybe check out this page --> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-colors-python-terminal/

Comment: Perhaps you want [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use good modules like [termcolor](https://pypi.org/project/termcolor/):

```
import sys
from termcolor import colored, cprint

text = colored('Hello, World!', 'red')
print(text)
cprint('Hello, World!', 'green', 'on_red')

print_red_on_cyan = lambda x: cprint(x, 'red', 'on_cyan')
print_red_on_cyan('Hello, World!')

for i in range(10):
    cprint(i, 'magenta', end=' ')

cprint("Attention!", 'red', attrs=['bold'], file=sys.stderr)
```

or [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/):

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```